# How do I target a span within a label element when a checkbox is checked using React Material UI createStyles?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to target the span, but haven't been able to do so. I want to be able to change the background color of the span when the checkbox is checked.

```
<div className={classes.container}>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid" />
  <label className={classes.label} htmlFor="checkboxid">
    <span className={classes.labelText}>Target</span>
  </label>
</div>

container: {
  '& input:checked': {
    '& label': {
      '& $labelText': {
         background: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While label is not inside the input but a sibiling you need to make use of the css [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `+`

In your context

```
const useSpanStyles = makeStyles({
    container: {
      '& input:checked + label': {
          '& span': {
              background: 'red'
          }
       },
    },
    label: {},
    labelText: {}
});


export function ComponentXYZ(){

    const classes = useSpanStyles();

    return (
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid" />
                <label className={classes.label} htmlFor="checkboxid">
                    <span className={classes.labelText}>Target</span>
                </label>
            </div>
    );
}
```

To be honest with you, if you are using MUI you should've used their [components](https://mui.com/components/checkboxes/#main-content) as its easier to compose and build UI with

Here's my suggestion

```
function ComponentXYZ(){

const [checked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

const checkedHandler = useCallback(function _checkedHandler(event: any) {
   setIsChecked(event.target.checked);
}, []);

return (
          <div>
              <FormGroup>
                  <FormControlLabel
                      control={<Checkbox
                          checked={checked}
                          onChange={checkedHandler}
                      />}
                      label={
                          <Typography style={{ background: checked ? 'red' : 'inherit' }}>
                              {'Label That change color'}
                          </Typography>
                      }
                  />
              </FormGroup>
          </div>
);

}
```